# Transition between two camera positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

In my game, I have two modes, walking and flying. Each has a separate camera behaviour (using the same camera). When changing the mode, I want a smooth transition between the camera positions.

Flying camera:

```cs
Vector3 moveCamTo = transform.position - transform.forward * 10.0f + Vector3.up * 5.0f;
float bias = 0.96f;
Camera.main.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position * bias + moveCamTo * (1.0f - bias);
Camera.main.transform.LookAt(transform.position + transform.forward * 30.0f);
```

Walking camera:

```cs
float smoothFactor = 0.5f;
float rotationSpeed = 13.0f;
Quaternion camTurnAngle = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed, Vector3.up);
_cameraOffset = camTurnAngle * _cameraOffset;
Vector3 newPos = transform.position + _cameraOffset;
Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(Camera.main.transform.position, newPos, smoothFactor);
Camera.main.transform.LookAt(transform.position);
```

I'm really struggling to figure it out. I've tried calling a method (like the following) when the mode changes, and I think this is probably along the right lines... but it doesn't actually work, doesn't transition at all because the next frame (in FixedUpdate), it sees what the mode is, and just uses that camera position.

```cs
void transitionCamera(Vector3 newPos) {
  float transitionDuration = 2.5f;
  float t = 0.0f;
  Vector3 startingPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
  while (t < 1.0f) {
    t += Time.deltaTime * (Time.timeScale/transitionDuration);
    Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startingPos, newPos, t);
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate any advice / info!

Answer (score 1):

Your method `transitionCamera` is all executed within a single frame!

You rather want to convert this into a [`Coroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
IEnumerator transitionCamera(Vector3 newPos) 
{
    var transitionDuration = 2.5f;
    var startingPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
    for (var t = 0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / transitionDuration) 
    {
        Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startingPos, newPos, t);

        yield return null;
    }

    Camera.main.transform.position = newPos;
}
```

And instead of just calling it you use [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

```
StartCorouine (transitionCamera(newPosition));
```